# increasing range parsing challenge with awk

Tags: bash, parsing, awk

I wrote this in response to Reddit's daily programmer challenge, and I would like to get some of your feedback on it to improve the code (it seems to work).  The challenge is as follows:

We are given a list of numbers in a "short-hand" range notation where only the significant part of the next number is written because we know the numbers are always increasing (ex. "1,3,7,2,4,1" represents [1, 3, 7, 12, 14, 21]). Some people use different separators for their ranges (ex. "1-3,1-2", "1:3,1:2", "1..3,1..2" represent the same numbers [1, 2, 3, 11, 12]) and they sometimes specify a third digit for the range step (ex. "1:5:2" represents [1, 3, 5]).

**NOTE**: For this challenge range limits are always inclusive.
Our job is to return a list of the complete numbers.
The possible separators are: ["-", ":", ".."]

Sample input:

```
104..02
545,64:11
```

Sample output:

```
104 105 106...200 201 202 # truncated for simplicity
545 564 565 566...609 610 611 # truncated for simplicity
```

My solution:

```
BEGIN { FS = "," }
function next_value(current_value, previous_value) {
    regexp = current_value "$"
    while(current_value <= previous_value || !(current_value ~ regexp)) {
        current_value += 10
    }
    return current_value;
}
{
    j = 0
    delete number_list
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        # handle fields with ranges
        if($i ~ /-|:|\.\./) {
            split($i, range, /-|:|\.\./)
            if(range[1] > range[2]) {
                if(j != 0) {
                    range[1] = next_value(range[1], number_list[j-1])
                    range[2] = next_value(range[2], range[1])
                }
                else
                    range[2] = next_value(range[2], range[1]);
            }

            if(range[3] == "")
                number_to_iterate_by = 1;
            else
                number_to_iterate_by = range[3];

            range_iterator = range[1]
            while(range_iterator <= range[2]) {
                number_list[j] = range_iterator
                range_iterator += number_to_iterate_by
                j++
            }
        }
        else {
            number_list[j] = $i
            j++
        }
    }
    # apply increasing range logic and print
    for(i = 0; i < j; i++ ) {
        if(i == 0) {
            if(NR != 1) printf "\n"
            current_value = number_list[i]
        }
        else {
            previous_value = current_value
            current_value = next_value(number_list[i], previous_value)
        }
        printf "%s ", current_value
    }
}
END { printf "\n" }
```

Comment: Why would you remove some of the sample input that someone else had already provided https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/5d1l7v/20161115_challenge_292_easy_increasing_range/, especially when it covers a requirement that the remaining inputs don't?

Comment: @EdMorton instructions are the same man, you could come up with your own inputs.

Comment: If I'd come up with my own inputs and outputs they'd have been wrong, and so useless, for the same reason my script worked the way it did - I did not understand your instructions. That is the point of the person posting the question providing the input/output, to clarify their textual requirements. You already had the sample input/output handed to you so why go to the trouble of deleting them and making the question less clear? Makes no sense.

Comment: @EdMorton I never said your solution was wrong, and if those were the inputs i posted then those were the ones I wanted.  I was more interested in seeing how you went about solving the problem I posted since you're a good programmer, don't take it the wrong way.  Edit: If I re-post challenges I'll do a better job next time as I get your point as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is BASH (Not AWK).
I believe it is a valid answer because the original challenge doesn't specify a language.

```
#!/bin/bash
mkord(){ local v=$1 dig base
          max=$2
          (( dig=10**${#v} , base=max/dig*dig , v+=base ))
          while (( v < max )); do (( v+=dig )); done
          max=$v
        }

while read line; do
    line="${line//[,\"]/ }" line="${line//[:-]/..}"
    IFS=' ' read -a arr <<<"$line"
    max=0 a='' res=''
    for val in "${arr[@]//../ }"; do
        IFS=" " read v1 v2 v3 <<<"$val"
        (( a==0 )) && max=$v1
        [[ $v1  ]] && mkord "$v1" "$max" && v1=$max
        [[ $v2  ]] && mkord "$v2" "$max" && v2=$max
        res=$res${a:+,}${v2:+\{}$v1${v2:+\.\.}$v2${v3:+\.\.}$v3${v2:+\}}
        a=1
    done
    (( ${#arr[@]} > 1 )) &&  res={$res}
    eval set -- $res
    echo "\"$*\""
done <"infile"
```

If the source of the tests is:

```
$ cat infile
"1,3,7,2,4,1"
"1-3,1-2"
"1:5:2"
"104-2"
"104..02"
"545,64:11"
```

The result will be:

```
"1 3 7 12 14 21"
"1 2 3 11 12"
"1 3 5"
"104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112"
"104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202"
"545 564 565 566 567 568 569 570 571 572 573 574 575 576 577 578 579 580 581 582 583 584 585 586 587 588 589 590 591 592 593 594 595 596 597 598 599 600 601 602 603 604 605 606 607 608 609 610 611"
```

This gets the list done in 7 milliseconds.

Comment: @EdMorton Nope. It is a range expansion with step `2`. Check the [original description (and solution) in here](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/5d1l7v/20161115_challenge_292_easy_increasing_range/)

Answer (score 1):

My solution using `gawk`, `RT` (It contains the input text that matched the text denoted by RS) and `next_n` function uses modulo operation for to find the next number based on the last

`cat range.awk`

```
BEGIN{
    RS="\\.\\.|,|:|-"
    start = ""
    end = 0
    temp = ""
}
function next_n(n, last){
    mod = last % (10**length(n))
    if(mod < n) return last - mod + n
    return last + ((10**length(n))-mod) + n
}
{
    if(RT==":" || RT==".." || RT=="-"){
        if(start=="") start = next_n($1,end)
        else temp = $1
    }else{
        if(start != ""){
            if(temp==""){
                end = next_n($1,start)
                step = 1
            }else {
                end = next_n(temp,start)
                step = $1
            }
            for(i=start; i<=end; i+=step) printf "%s ", i
            start = ""
            temp = ""
        }else{
            end = next_n($1,end)
            printf "%s ", end
        }
    }
}
END{
    print ""
}
```

**TEST 1**

```
echo "104..02" | awk -f range.awk
```

**OUTPUT 1**

```
104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202
```

**TEST 2**

```
echo "545,64:11" | awk -f range.awk
```

**OUTPUT 2**

```
545 564 565 566 567 568 569 570 571 572 573 574 575 576 577 578 579 580 581 582 583 584 585 586 587 588 589 590 591 592 593 594 595 596 597 598 599 600 601 602 603 604 605 606 607 608 609 610 611
```

**TEST 3**

```
echo "2..5,7,2-1,2:1,0-3,2-7,8..0,4,4,2..1" | awk -f range.awk
```

**OUTPUT 3**

```
2 3 4 5 7 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 40 41 42 43 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 64 74 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91
```

**TEST 4 with step**

```
echo "1:5:2,99,88..7..3" | awk -f range.awk"
```

**OUTPUT 4**

```
1 3 5 99 188 191 194 197
```